# Applying multiple ACF Group fields to the same div

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created [two Group fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgjFg.png) in ACF to select different padding options for desktop and mobile, but I'm having trouble applying both Group fields to the same div.

I tried nesting one loop inside of the other:

```
<?php if( have_rows('desktop_padding') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('desktop_padding') ): the_row(); ?>
    
        <?php if( have_rows('mobile_padding') ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('mobile_padding') ): the_row(); ?>
    
                <div class="padding-top-<?php the_sub_field('desktop_padding_top'); ?> padding-bottom-<?php the_sub_field('desktop_padding_bottom'); ?> mobile-padding-top-<?php the_sub_field('mobile_padding_top'); ?> mobile-padding-bottom-<?php the_sub_field('mobile_padding_bottom'); ?>">
                
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
                
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've also tried using conditional operators in the same loop:

```
<?php if( have_rows('desktop_padding') && have_rows('mobile_padding') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('desktop_padding') && have_rows('mobile_padding') ): the_row(); ?>
    
        <div class="padding-top-<?php the_sub_field('desktop_padding_top'); ?> padding-bottom-<?php the_sub_field('desktop_padding_bottom'); ?> mobile-padding-top-<?php the_sub_field('mobile_padding_top'); ?> mobile-padding-bottom-<?php the_sub_field('mobile_padding_bottom'); ?>">
                
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But both of these methods broke the code..

What is an acceptable way to code both Group fields to the same div so that the padding classes are applied correctly?

Comment: Can you post the relevant output of `var_dump(get_fields());`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I tried pasting `var_dump(get_fields());` inside and outside of the above code block but there was no output from the browser at all.

Comment: Did you try viewing source? It might be hidden by CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can’t nest these kinds of loops because their data structures aren’t originally nested, they are adjacent. These means will need to get the data in two different loops. For this kind of thing I’d recommend not doing that logic in the HTML area, but instead move it elsewhere for ease of reading, too.

The below is untested (sorry, don’t have ACF handy right now) but hopefully puts you on the right path.

```php
<?php

$padding = [];
if( have_rows('desktop_padding') ) {
    the_row();
    $padding[] = 'padding-top-' . get_sub_field('desktop_padding_top');
    $padding[] = 'padding-bottom-' . get_sub_field('desktop_bottom_top');
}
if( have_rows('mobile_padding') ) {
    the_row();
    $padding[] = 'mobile-padding-top-' . get_sub_field('mobile_padding_top');
    $padding[] = 'mobile-padding-bottom-' . get_sub_field('mobile_bottom_top');
}
?>

<div class="<?php esc_attr_e(implode(' ', $padding)); ?">

</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the code only pulls in the variable for desktop_padding_top but not the others unfortunately. Here's the output on the div when inspecting the element:
`<div class="padding-top-med padding-bottom-">`

Comment: Shouldn't there still be while loops involved? Or are those already built into the if statments above using {...}?